# Memory efficient way to load large entity set for data export

Tags: 8, entities, importing-exporting

I'm working on an Excel exporting feature in a Drupal 8 site.

Obviously, I can load all entites of certain type like this:

```php
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();

$entity_query = \Drupal::service('entity.query')->get('some_type');
$entity_query->sort('created', 'DESC');

$ids = $entity_query->execute();
$entites = $this->storage->loadMultiple($ids);

foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    // build some Excel row with the entity information
    // ...
}
```

But if you're doing this on a large entity set, you'll be running out of memory very soon. I think the reason why Drupal would run out of memory is the extensive caching involves in the entity query and loading process.

Is there a more memory-efficient way to load an indefinite size of entity set without running out of memory?

(Note: Let's pretend the Excel library is very clever and do not take up memory. That's another issue for another day.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Batches allow heavy processing to be spread out over several page
>   requests, ensuring that the processing does not get interrupted
>   because of a PHP timeout, while allowing the user to receive feedback
>   on the progress of the ongoing operations. It also can reduce out of
>   memory situations.
>
> <sub>Source: [Example: Batch API](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/batch_example%21batch_example.module/group/batch_example/8.x-1.x)</sub>

You need to use the Batch API. There is no official docs for D8, but you can look at the [batch_example](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/-/tree/3.x/modules/batch_example) module and the [CSV Import](https://github.com/xurizaemon/csvimport) module.

Good conceptual read, [Drupal 8 Batch Processing](https://www.bluetext.com/drupal-8-batch-processing/) but a bad code example.

Comment: Not sure if the linked article is such a good read. It does wrong what most articles on Batch API do wrong: Processing everything in just one single batch operation. Whereas this needs to happen in multiple operations each processing a chunk of entities.

Comment: There's this [csvimport](https://github.com/xurizaemon/csvimport) sample module I co-maintain which actually does it right. Though it adds one operation per CSV line. One operation per every 5-10 lines would probably have been fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the memory footprint you can load single entities and then use resetCache():

```
$ids = $entity_query->execute();

foreach ($ids as $id) {
  $entity = $this->storage->load($id);
  // build some Excel row with the entity information
  // ...
  // release entity from memory
  $storage->resetCache([$id]);
}
```

Comment: The con of just doing this would be that you could potentially run into a PHP timeout, but good to know.

Comment: @NoSssweat, yes, I know, but the question is specifically about loading entities in a more memory-efficient way and not everyone googling this might be interested in a batch solution, which is in general the better solution though and it is good to have both answers.